# Hi , is it possible to use c++ file to execute a executable file?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using publisher and subscribers(C++) , i am thinking whether is it possible to execute a executable file using a int receive from the publisher?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252458/hi-,-is-it-possible-to-use-c++-file-to-execute-a-executable-file?/) by [lolz733](https://answers.ros.org/users/28032/lolz733/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-01-20**:
Could you add some sentences on what you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

std::system("yourExecutabel")

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0